# Magento - How to implement a custom questionfield for the registration?

Tags: magento, captcha

I have got some troubles with spam registrations, as i try to avoid captchas i want to implement a question.

So how to add a custom field into the registration that has to be entered a certain text?

For example i want to ask: What color has a banana?

The question has not to change it could be the same all day long as i dont expect the bots to adapt.

Comment: It's a very simple attribute creation + display ... Where are you stuck ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/30316/